# Finding relative extrema

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, gre-exam

For the following problem, we are asked which of the following statements is true for $f(x,y)=x^2-2xy+y^3$

A) $f$ has all its relative extrema on the line $y=x$

B) $f$ has all its relative extrema on the parabola $x=y^2$

C) $f$ has a relative minimum at $(0,0)$

D) $f$ has an absolute minimum at $(\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{3})$

E) $f$ has an absolute minimum at (1,1)

How would one go about solving this problem within 3 minutes?

Comment: You should see very quickly that A) is true, B) is false, C) is false (think about $y^3$). Note that $f(x,y)=(x-y)^2+(y^3-y^2)$. What does this tell you?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you know A is true?

Comment: A) is true because $\partial f/\partial x = 2(x-y)=0$ on the line $y=x$.